# Can't change color of buttons without changing colorPrimery, kotlin - android

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, button, themes

I'm new android developer. I am trying to change the background of button and set the black color on it. (the color of button is purple)
I wrote this code on a body of button in main activity:

android:background="@color/black"

color "black" has defined in colors.xml:

#FF000000

but color of my button is still purple (it's not black)
I found this purple color in "themes" named "colorPrimary".
when I change the "colorPrimary" to black, the color of button changed but the problem is that "colorPrimary" applies to all buttons and I can't have two button with diferent colors in my app :(

how can I change the color of buttons without changing color primary?
how can I have two different buttons with different colors?

Answer (score 0):

That's because [material buttons](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button) use `backgrountTint` attribute to colorize their background not `background` attribute, So replace `background` attribute with:

```
<Button
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="#FF000000"/>
```